# Is it possible to customize the "Done" Button and bar position of the InAppBrowser?

Tags: cordova, cordova-2.0.0, inappbrowser

I have an application where I open an external URL with InAppBrowser plugin, so I want to change the position of bar where done button appear…

Is it possible to customize the "Done" Button of the InAppBrowser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes we can customize ...

ioS only.

1. closebuttoncaption - set to a string that will be the caption for
   the "Done" button. Note that you will have to localize this value
   yourself.
2. toolbar - set to 'yes' or 'no' to turn the toolbar on or off for the
   InAppBrowser (defaults to 'yes')

But here you can not change the position of the status bar and done button.

Answer (score 3):

You can now change the position of the toolbar by setting `toolbarposition=top`.  It defaults to `toolbarposition=bottom`.

As mentioned earlier you can also customize the text of the Done button by setting `closebuttoncaption=Back` or whatever you like.

The latest InAppBrowser docs can now be found [here](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser) (they've moved).

Answer (score 1):

Phonegap v2.9.0 allows you to customize certain aspects of the InAppBrowser.

More can be found [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#insertCSS).

Answer (score 1):

```
window.open('http://url/', '_blank', 'toolbarposition=top');
```

**toolbarposition**: Set to top or bottom (default is bottom). Causes the toolbar to be at the top or bottom of the window.

**closebuttoncaption**: set to a string to use as the Done button's caption. Note that you need to localize this value yourself.

Find all options [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser)

Answer (score 1):

Just sharing an example passing multiple options in a more organized way:

```
// inAppBrowser
this.openUrl = url => {
    if (typeof cordova === 'undefined') return;

    let options = [
        'location=no',
        'toolbarposition=top',
        'enableViewportScale=yes',
        'transitionstyle=fliphorizontal',
        'closebuttoncaption=Back to the App'
    ];

    window.cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, '_blank', options.join());
};
```

I'm sharing because I missed on the docs the part that says that multiple options should be passed as a single string, comma separated, no spaces (except, I guess, the 'closebuttoncaption' option that accepts normal spaces.